# Compatibility between DirectX 9 and DirectX 10 shaders

Tags: c#, xna, directx, shader, hlsl

I am a beginner to game development and as I am used to programming in C# I decided to go for XNA. I've been playing around with it for a while and now I am learning the basics of HLSL shaders, I have noticed in the MSDN documentation that there have been some syntax changes in HLSL between DirectX 9 and DirectX 10, for example, the [Sampler type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509644%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Since I am having some troubles with my desktop pc, I am using my laptop which video card only supports DirectX 9.0c. Then I'm gonna have to write my shaders using the DirectX 9 syntax, right? So I am wondering, **will my HLSL shaders written using the DirectX 9 syntax work on a system running DirectX 10 (or higher)?**

Comment: You may give this question a try on the gamedev sister site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mjmarsh, thank you, posted it there.

Comment: This answer might help you:


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853997/directx-9-hlsl-vs-directx-10-hlsl-syntax-the-same/2859820#2859820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you develop your Shaders for DirectX 9, then they will almost certainly work on a DirectX 10 Graphics card.  You would only have a problem if you were to write them the other way around.